# Disable Server Login upon Updates Reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, login

- I have a co-located Dedicated Server running Windows 2008 R2.
- It is a Live server running my sites (wordpress, joomla, etc)
- I administer it via Remote Desktop.

Everytime I do the Microsoft OS Updates (Security updates, Patches, etc) the system asks for a reboot.  Upon performing the reboot, the server gets caught I think on the Control + Alt + Delete login screen which I cant get to. (I'm assuming that this is where its getting caught, not 100% sure)

so the server never comes back up neither do my sites.  I cant even login via Remote Desktop as it says something like Server is Unavailable.

it costs me $60 to get it back running each time for Hands on Fee from the hosting company to physically go to the machine and enter the password and log me in.

I'm alway scared to reboot thinking I will lose my connection back in.

What can I do so solve this?

I hope I was clear in my question and overview.

Comment: This is a dedicated server, and they don't give you OOB console access? Time to find another hosting provider.

Comment: This is my own hardware being co-located in chicago.  If it was just a dedicated server, then I would think about moving...  Sorry, also, what's "OOB console access"? thanks

Comment: "Out of band". Dell has their DRAC cards, HP has iLO, etc. They give you out-of-band access to console, power management, virtual drives, etc. They're more or less a necessity for reasons you're discovering.

Comment: Something's not right here, you should not have to login to a sever from the console for remote access to work. I'm in Chicago, if you need someone to work through this drop me a line.

Comment: So basically its a hardware card right?  You mentioned some cards for Big Brand names...anything available for no-name brands?Something I would have to install myself, when I go to chicago. :)  What are my other options right now?

Comment: My server just rebooted and there we are...at a point where I cant login or even RDC in...  There must be a solution to this...anybody?

Answer (score 1):

Next time it happens ask the hosting company tell you if the system is actually sitting at the CTRL + ALT + DEL screen after reboot or is it at the BIOS screen waiting for a user to acknowledge some error or warning related to the hardware.

If the problem is the later it is most likely a hardware issue that your hosting provider will need to assist with. If it's making it to the Windows CTRL + ALT + DEL screen then you should check your windows services and make sure remote desktop service is set to start automatically. If it's set to automatic but failing to start the windows event log may indicate why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend looking into getting an IP KVM installed so you have access to the console remotely.  That will save you from having to pay $60 every time something goes wrong.

There is no reason why you should have to login before things start working.  Remote desktop should be available by the time it gets the login prompt. There is probably a bios error they are acknowledging.  Possibly "no keyboard, press f1 to continue" which they wouldnt see when they hook up their keyboard to fix it.

If you cant get an ip kvm get them to check for the "prompt on error" bios settings.